# How to use filter with switchMap?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable that should watch every Chat Message that has a type `'private'`

So what I'm trying to do is to use the function `filter()` from rxjs to watch every Chat Message that has a type `private` so I can use it in my variable `chatMessagePrivate$`

Here is what I tried:

```
export type ChatType = 'private' | 'standard';

export class ChatMessage {
  uid?: string;
  chatRoomUid: string;
  type: ChatType;
}

chatMessagePrivate$: Observable<ChatMessage[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatMessagePrivate$ = this.chatRoom$.pipe(
    switchMap((chatRoom: ChatRoom) => this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid) // this function returns every message from the uid of the chatroom
      .filter(chatRoom => 'private')
      )
    );
}
```

And I'm getting the following error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

How can I use `filter()` to get all ChatMessage with the type `'private'` ?

Comment: You're in fact using `Array.filter()` and not `filter()` operator from RxJS.

Comment: What type does `this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$` return?

Comment: @fridoo An observable of type ChatMessage[]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` of RxJS v6+ (I assume you use v6+) is a pipeable operator. So you need to use it like:

```
this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid).pipe(
   filter(cr => cr.type === 'private')
);
```

For further reading: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

---

**UPDATE:**

Since the response is an array, you need to use `Array.filter`. You can do it like following:

```
this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid).pipe(
   map(crArr => crArr.filter(cr => cr.type === 'private'))
);
```

Comment: I get that `type` does not exist on type Observable<ChatMessage[]>, I didn't downvoted you though

Comment: No worries about the downvote :) It happens time to time. I updated the answer according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Saves lots of time and relief from headaches.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` expects a `boolean` so try this:

```
.filter(chatRoom => chatRoom.type === 'private')
```

**IF**
this `this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid)` returns an `Observable` then you might have to use `pipe`:

```
this.chatMessagePrivate$ = this.chatRoom$.pipe(
switchMap((chatRoom: ChatRoom) => this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid)) // this function returns every message from the uid of the chatroom
  ,filter(chatRoom => chatRoom.type === 'private')
  )
);
```

Comment: Small edit: you can't use dot notation here. It needs to be added as an argument to the `pipe`.

Comment: @WillAlexander i think he is using Array.filter() here but he mixed it in his question

Comment: He's calling it on an Observable though, so it won't work…

Comment: Actually it looks like he's trying to use `switchMap` on something that isn't an Observable…more needs to be modified here I think

Comment: @WillAlexander I think he is using observable, becase he is calling `filter` on the `getAllByChatRoomUid$`. The dollar sign in the end is usually used for observables or subjects.

Comment: So like I said, either the filter has to go in the `pipe` as an RxJS operator, or he needs to change the syntax of the `switchMap` call, as he's trying to call `Array.filter` on an Observable

Comment: There's no reason to `pipe` the `filter` to the inner Observable. Best to keep things clean by adding it to the outer `pipe` and avoid unnecessary embedding.

Comment: @WillAlexander fair enough

Answer (score 2):

In case you should use [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux) actions, you could use the special [`ofType`](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/ofType) filter from RxJS to retrieve exactly all actions whose chat type equals "private".

```
this.chatMessagePrivate$ = this.chatRoom$.pipe(
    ofType('private'),
    switchMap((chatRoom: ChatRoom) => this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid) // this function returns every message from the uid of the chatroom
      )
    );
```

---

Otherwise, without redux and in case `this.chatRoom$` already contains the information whether the chat room is private or not, I would suggest you attach the `filter` before the actual service method call:

```
this.chatMessagePrivate$ = this.chatRoom$.pipe(
    filter(chatRoom:  => chatRoom.type === 'private'),  // in case the "type" property exists
    switchMap((chatRoom: ChatRoom) => this.chatMessageService.getAllByChatRoomUid$(chatRoom.uid)
    );
```